# Filter duplicate nodes before inserting into XML field

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am using an xml field to store suggestions for books in this format:

```
<Books>
  <Book id="1" score="2" />
  <Book id="2" score="3" />
</Books>
```

At some point I need to add suggestions into this xml. This is done with these statements:

```
DECLARE @books XML;
SELECT @books = Suggestions.query('//books/book') 
FROM User
WHERE UserId = @UserId

UPDATE User
SET Suggestions.modify('insert sql:variable("@books") as first into (//books)[1]')
WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

How can I make sure I'm not inserting nodes that already exist (based on the id attribute only).

Comment: One hint: `as first into (//books)[1]` won't work due to the small "b" in "books"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve it could be creating new XML variable with only new values.

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #User(UserId INT, Suggestions XML, Name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #User(UserId, Suggestions, Name)
VALUES (1, 
       '<Books>
          <Book id="1" score="2" />
          <Book id="2" score="3" />
        </Books>'
        ,'John');

DECLARE @books XML =N'<Book id="1" score="2" />
                      <Book id="2" score="3" />
                      <Book id="3" score="4" />
                      <Book id="4" score="4" />';
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = 1;
       ,@only_new_books XML;

;WITH books AS
(
   SELECT id    = s.c.value('@id', 'INT'),
          score = s.c.value('@score', 'INT')
   FROM @books.nodes('/Book') AS s(c)
), suggestions AS
( 
  SELECT UserId, 
      id    = s.c.value('@id', 'INT'),
      score = s.c.value('@score', 'INT')
  FROM #User
  CROSS APPLY Suggestions.nodes('//Books/Book') AS s(c)
  WHERE UserId = @UserId
)
SELECT @only_new_books = (SELECT b.id AS '@id',
                                 b.score AS '@score'
                          FROM books b
                          LEFT JOIN suggestions s
                            ON b.id = s.id
                          WHERE s.id IS NULL
                          FOR XML PATH('Book'),TYPE
                          );

UPDATE #User
SET Suggestions.modify('insert sql:variable("@only_new_books") 
                        as first into (//Books)[1]')
WHERE UserId = @UserId;

SELECT * FROM #User;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/428911)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦══════════════════════════════════════╦══════╗
║ UserId ║             Suggestions              ║ Name ║
╠════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╬══════╣
║      1 ║ <Books>                              ║ John ║    
║        ║    <Book id="3" score="4" />         ║      ║
║        ║    <Book id="4" score="4" />         ║      ║
║        ║    <Book id="1" score="2" />         ║      ║
║        ║    <Book id="2" score="3" />         ║      ║
║        ║ </Books>                             ║      ║
╚════════╩══════════════════════════════════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Hi @lad2025. I've to say that I admire your rocket wise start on SO. You've started short before me and I'm quite fast too but nothing against you :-) (voted this, still thinking that this solutions misses to handle a changed score... But the OP did not state anything about and accepted - so it seems to be perfect) Happy coding! :-)

Comment: @Shnugo Really nice to hear it :) If user want to merge data(update changed rows) then your solution is better , if not my is sufficient. Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

#### If you really want nothing else than a check before you insert read this

Just change your code to

```
DECLARE @id INT = @books.value('(/Book/@id)[1]','int'); --the book-id of the "new" suggestion

UPDATE User
SET Suggestions.modify('insert sql:variable("@books") as first into (//Books)[1]')
WHERE UserId = @UserId
  AND Suggestions.exist('//Book[@id=sql:variable("@id")]')=0
```

#### If you want to "merge" two Books-structures read this

```
DECLARE @xml1 XML= --the existing XML
'<Books>
    <Book id="1" score="2" />
    <Book id="2" score="3" />
    <Book id="4" score="4" />
</Books>';

DECLARE @xml2 XML= --the XML with new or changed data
'<Books>
    <Book id="1" score="3" />
    <Book id="2" score="3" />
    <Book id="5" score="5" />
</Books>';

WITH Xml1 AS
(
    SELECT One.Book.value('@id','int') AS id
          ,One.Book.value('@score','int') AS score
    FROM @xml1.nodes('/Books/Book') AS One(Book)
)
,Xml2 AS
(
    SELECT One.Book.value('@id','int') AS id
          ,One.Book.value('@score','int') AS score
    FROM @xml2.nodes('/Books/Book') AS One(Book)
)
SELECT ISNULL(Xml2.id,Xml1.id) AS [@id]
      ,ISNULL(Xml2.score,Xml1.score) AS [@score]
FROM Xml1
FULL OUTER JOIN Xml2 ON Xml1.id=Xml2.id
ORDER BY ISNULL(Xml2.id,Xml1.id)
FOR XML PATH('Book'),ROOT('Books');

/*
<Books>
  <Book id="1" score="3" /> --score changed
  <Book id="2" score="3" /> --unchanged
  <Book id="4" score="4" /> --remained
  <Book id="5" score="5" /> --new
</Books>
*/
```

You might pack this into an UDF and use it like

```
UPDATE User 
SET Suggestions=dbo.Function(Suggestions,@NewSuggestions)
WHERE UserID=@userID
```

#### If you want to insert new and change existing read this

Regrettfully the `MERGE` statement is not allowed here. You'd need an `UPDATE` command in the `MATCHED` and as well as in the `NOT MATCHED` section...

This is my suggestion:

```
CREATE TABLE #User (UserID INT,Suggestions XML);
INSERT INTO #User VALUES
 (1,
'<Books>
  <Book id="1" score="2" />
  <Book id="2" score="3" />
</Books>');
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateOrInsertSuggestion(@UserID INT, @id INT, @score INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XmlNode XML=(SELECT @id AS [@id],@score AS [@score] FOR XML PATH('Book'));

    DECLARE @UsersSuggestions XML=
    (
        SELECT Suggestions
        FROM #User
        WHERE UserID=@UserID
    );

    IF @UsersSuggestions.exist('//Book[@id=sql:variable("@id")]')=1
        SET @UsersSuggestions.modify('replace value of (//Book[@id=sql:variable("@id")]/@score)[1] with sql:variable("@score")');
    ELSE
        SET @UsersSuggestions.modify('insert sql:variable("@XmlNode") as first into (//Books)[1]');

    UPDATE #User SET Suggestions=@UsersSuggestions 
    WHERE UserID=@UserID;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.UpdateOrInsertSuggestion 1,2,2; --change score to 2 on id=2
SELECT * FROM #User;

/*
<Books>
  <Book id="1" score="2" />
  <Book id="2" score="2" />
</Books>
*/

EXEC dbo.UpdateOrInsertSuggestion 1,5,5; --insert new
SELECT * FROM #User;

/*
<Books>
  <Book id="5" score="5" />
  <Book id="1" score="2" />
  <Book id="2" score="2" />
</Books>
*/
GO


DROP PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateOrInsertSuggestion;
DROP TABLE #User;
GO
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to merge(update/insert) 2 xmls using only `.modify()` and XPath/XQuery (some kind of loop maybe) without using `.nodes()/.value()`.

Comment: @lad2025, let me know if you find one :-) I love such riddles and puzzled around for a while. My approach was the second (merge XMLs, pack this in a function and do the UPDATE from there...

Comment: @Shungo I will search, if I won't find then there will be question with bounty(I share the link)  :)

Comment: @lad2025 waiting for it :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080942/sql-server-merge-two-xml-using-only-modify :)